# Why does Kotlin toIntOrNull() returns null on large numbers?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have the following code to check if the value is `Int` or `null` and further check if it is below a certain number:

```
            binding.RootLayout.forEach {
                if (it is EditText) {

                    val intOrNull = it.text.toString().toIntOrNull()

                    if (intOrNull == null) {

                        count += 1
                    } else if (intOrNull > 100000) {
                        overTheLimitExist = true
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is, when I enter some number like `123456789` or below, it correctly identify it as (1) `Int` and (2) above the preset limit. However, if I enter a larger number such as `12345678900` it incorrectly identify it as `null`.

I search online for the `toIntOrNull` but they didn't say anything about a limit to the function.

Comment: Max limit of `Int` is approximately `2*10^9` (4byte). Over that until approx `4*10^18` use `Long`(8byte). Or else `BigInteger` which can store number upto infinity :P (just kidding it can store upto ~18GB of RAM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`12345678900` is larger than Integer's [max value](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) (2^31-1) , hence the implementation of `toIntOrNull` returns null, as `12345678900` doesn't fit in 4 bytes.

You can use `toLongOrNull` or `toBigIntegerOrNull` for really big numbers.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this. Is there a performance penalty to `toLongOrNull` though?

Comment: no performance impact, though `long` takes 8 bytes memory

Comment: Thanks, I don't save the value anyway. I'm just doing a conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this problem is for limit of int type
(-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) you should use another type such as "Long" or BigNumber java class. 
you can test 1 bigger than this range (2147483648) or 1 smaller (2147483646) and see the result.
I hope this help to you. 
sorry for my English.
```